# Is there a function in R that could help fixing data in a data base?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame, where `ID` is a person code. The `amount` variable must be the same during the hold period, but I find that in certain cases the values are rounded.

| ID | period | amount | share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1x | 202001 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202002 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202003 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202004 | **100** | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202005 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202006 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 2x | 202105 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202106 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202107 | **110** | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202108 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202109 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202110 | 111.11 | 11.11 |

I have to find all the similar cases and modify the value in amount. The case is that this round staff could happen with different persons and in different periods. I wish to get this df:

| ID | period | amount | share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1x | 202001 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202002 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202003 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202004 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202005 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 1x | 202006 | 99.87 | 9.87 |
| 2x | 202105 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202106 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202107 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202108 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202109 | 111.11 | 11.11 |
| 2x | 202110 | 111.11 | 11.11 |

Anyone has to fix something like this?

Comment: What defines the hold period?  The column `period`?  What defines the "correct" value?  The first valuye in each period, the first  non-integer value in the period?  An `amount` that is not an integer multiple of `share`? Something else?

Comment: Agree with @Limey that this can be achieved with two additions.  1) A column that defines the hold period.  "period" in your example data doesn't seem to do this.  2) A very specific logic to correct values (for example, within each hold period, set all values to the mode).

Comment: @Limey The first value in each year it must be the correct value. Share is a rate that becomes from the amount and the discount rate. It has to be fixed for the whole period as well.

Comment: It seems those `period ` and `share` columns do nothing with the `amount` column. There is no interaction between them. Actually the values of the `amount` column must simply remain constant for each unique `ID`s. Am I correct?

Comment: @Maya_Cent yes! it has to be. It looks like it i buy something that cost 120 and y split it over 12 month, y have to pay the same amonunt(100) each month and i have have to pay 100 + interest. The colunm share its the interets rate i have to pay in adition to the monthly amount

Comment: Year?  What year?  There's no year in your data frame.  Unless you want me to make assumptions about the format of `period`.  There's too much that's assumed, unclear or not specified in this post.  Voting to close for lack of clarity.